# Jackrabbit | How to run SQL insert query

Tags: java, jackrabbit

My application is using the Jackrabbit repository for storing images, but now I need to create a script for that. So, my question is there any way for storing images in the Jackrabbit repo through a script?

Comment: Do you work accedently with AEM or Magnolia cms?

Comment: No man, I don't work with them.

Answer (score 0):

"SQL" (it's not really SQL) in the JCR API is only used for querying stuff.

To actually store something, you'll likely need to use the javax.jcr API.

Comment: Tnx a lot man! Do you maybe have some example for this?